# Контролер не видит Index.cshtml ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, связывание-данных

Вот мой Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
    <form method="post">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
        <div>Enter your ID:</div>
        <input type="text"  name="ID"/>
        <div>Enter your message:</div>
        <input type="text" name="Body"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
    </form>
```

А вот контролер с которым он не взаимодействует:

```
namespace TEST.Controllers
{
    public class MessageController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(string ID, string Body)
        {
            string authData = $"ID: {ID}   Body: {Body}";
            return Content(authData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код вполне рабочий. Уточните вашу проблему. Дайте больше информации о типе проекта и прочем.

Comment: В каком каталоге лежит Index.cshtml? Покажите структуру проекта.